# MSDeploy broken on Team Build Server after Installing Visual Studio SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, tfsbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have had nightly builds set up and working for a few months until now.  I installed Visual Studio 2012 SDK on Saturday and now my builds are not deploying via MSDeploy.

My build server has Visual Studio 2012 installed.  It also has the admin console for both TFS 2010 and 2012 installed.  We aren't using 2012 yet so I have the service turned off.

In my build definition, under Process/Advanced/MSBuild Arguments, I have this:

```
    /p VisualStudioVersion=11.0;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=DeployToDEV;username=xxx;password=xxx;WebPublishPipelineProjectName=dev
```

My project has a targets file called dev.wpp.targets.  Inside of this file I have a DeployToDEV target.  I basically followed the instructions from "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine" so I can deploy to multiple servers at the same time.  It worked beautifully until now.

I get no errors and no indication that Web Deploy has been run or not.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: I asked our IT dept to roll back the server to the day before I installed the SDK.  It works again!  I will think twice before installing anything else on my build server again.  What a pain in the neck!